# Bootstrap formatting inline in one row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Solved: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/7whzzhyh/4/)
here is what I wanted, sample:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10" name="name" placeholder="name" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="birthday" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Birthday</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10" name="name" placeholder="name" />
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

.css:

```
.form-inline .form-group {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

END

UPDATE:

I see where my problem is but i have `form-horizontal` that I want and if i change it to `form-inline` everything else is messed up please have a look at the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/7whzzhyh/1/)

How do I make it inline in one row without spacing as shown in the screen shot:

```
<form class="navbar-form form-horizontal" role="search" style="padding:0" _lpchecked="1">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Location</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" id="src1" placeholder="Search" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" id="srch2" placeholder="State" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" id="srch3" placeholder="City" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

as you can see spacing between the input:
[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/7whzzhyh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`form-inline`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) instead of `form-horizontal`:

```
<form class="navbar-form form-inline" role="search" style="padding:0" _lpchecked="1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Location</label>
    <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" id="src1" placeholder="Search" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" id="srch2" placeholder="State" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" id="srch3" placeholder="City" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ajXO0EmAZq)

Comment: 1+ Thanks @nthall I see where my problem is but i have `form-horizontal` that I want and if i change it to `form-inline` everything else is messed up please have a look at the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/7whzzhyh/1/

Comment: That fiddle demonstrates a very different question/problem than the code in your question here.

Answer (score 0):

Simple calculation: `col-sm-3 * 4 + col-sm-2` == `col-sm-14` Which is not good. You should make sure that the total will not exceed **12** cols for each row.

Suggestion - change the first `col-sm-3` to `col-sm-1`

Comment: i have tried to be within 12 but still does not work

Comment: OK, so take a look at @nthall answer.